# Fixing a error in connectivity ms access in visual basic?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I receive this message error:

The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine.

I want to connect my database in vb thru ms access. What do i do and how to fix that error message. I already installed a microsoft database engine 2010. But it not works.